# Border doesn't adjust it's content automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So here's the problem:

```
<window>
    <border>
        <grid>
            <border>

            </border>
        </grid>
    </border>
</window
```

Now all the borders have a dropshadow around them. Means my window is a bit larger and transparent, but has a border in it to get this fancy shadow around it.

But as i have multiple shadows, they overlap at some point and then it looks all weird :(

Is there the possibility that i can make the outer border cut its content? So that the inner content cant overlap the border?

I don't know if its clear, so here's a screenshot:

Look at the window's red titlebar's edges to the right and to the left:

[image]

Comment: Try putting it in a grid

Comment: Didn't help as the whole window content is inside a grid and inside this grid, the shadow around a rectangle manages to overlap with the border outside of the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clip the contents of elements in WPF using ClipToBounds.

```
<Window ClipToBounds="True">
...
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

So heres the complete solution i've got now:

```
<window>
    <border Tag="Thats the window shadow">
        <border Tag="Thats just for keeping the rest inside the window">
            <WindowContent>
                ...
            </WindowContent>
        </border>
    </border>
</window>
```